# Running a kinect on Raspberry Pi - Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, kinect, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run Vision Processing python code, through Raspberry Pi with the Microsoft Kinect camera.
I have perfectly working code running on Ubuntu but it fails to perform the same on the RPi.
I think I have all libraries installed on it...

I even tryied the following simple code:

```
    import freenect
    ir, data = freenect.sync_get_video(format=freenect.VIDEO_IR_8BIT)
    print ir
```

It doesn't work, it gets stuck.
What could the reason?
Maybe the kinect and the raspberry Pi dont work together?

Note: When I try "freenect-glview" I get: "Number of devices found: 1"

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by "doesn't work". It should definitely be possible to use a Kinect with a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I dont get any output. its just stuck.. :(

Comment: For example - a really simple code - Screen capture [link](http://tinypic.com/r/30agrcw/6). Please note that the program hangs during running..

Comment: I haven't actually tried this myself but this issue was discussed at the RPI forums (sry, don't have the link at hand). It seems nobody got video working, yet. All that works is controlling the motor.

Comment: Here people sad that they success to do this - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openkinect/LrqxxviZZnI

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using OpenNI SDK. I tried and it works with [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/) Also do you have a powered USB hub as PI can't generate enough energy to power Kinect.

Comment: No, i have not tried it, But I think it does not suit my needs.. Maybe I'm wrong.. can i get a IR video matrix with the openNI? and yes I used a powered USB.. thx :)

Comment: You can see the differences of SDK's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086981/what-is-the-difference-between-openni-and-openkinect Both have access to frame data.

Comment: I am sure we can do it on PI. Isn't the PandaBoard costlier option?

Answer (score 0):

Kinect does not work on RPI due to an usb driver bug :

> Linux Driver Issues
>
> Shortly after the Raspberry Pi was released it was confirmed that there were a number of issues with the Linux USB driver for the
>   SMSC95xx chip.
>   These included problems with USB 1.x peripherals that use split transactions, a fixed number of channels (causing problems with
>   Kinect) and the way the ARM processor handles the SMSC95xx interrupts.
>   [2] [3] A large number of fixes were included in the
>   2012-08-19-Wheezy-raspbian Linux image.

source http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals